# Pushing items from a text file into queue of struct types

Tags: c++, struct, queue

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<queue>

using namespace std;

const int process_cnt=22;


struct process{

  int at;
  float bt;
  float rt;
  int tat;
  int wt;};

queue<process*> ready_q;
queue<process*> init_q;

int main(){

  ifstream inData;

   inData.open("input.txt");
   while(inData){
```

I think this is causing the error since the Entry from the file should not be made into the current front.BTW,the file has two values separated by a space in each line.The entry pointer points to the front element.I thought pointing entry to back() might work but that is not working as well.

```
   process *entry = init_q.front();//ERROR


   inData >>entry->at>>entry->bt;
   init_q.push(entry);
   }
  cout<<"Read Successful in read_file"<<endl;

  inData.close();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Search the internet for "StackOverflow c++ read file struct" for some examples.

Comment: Why are you pushing *pointers* to objects and not the object instances?  Pointers to objects may lead to a memory leak nightmare.  Also, if you insist on pointers, use smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Only addressing the problem marked "//ERROR".
At this point the init_q is empty and front() is undefined. 
Look at the documentation for deque, the default container for queue. 
[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/front)